# How to disconnect people from voice channel using discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, disconnect

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    print(member)
    if str(member) == str("The_person_I_want_to_ban#his_code"):
        await client.guild.member.disconnect()
```

It says

```
in on_voice_state_update
await client.guild.member.disconnect()
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

I guess I have to change the client in client.guild.member.disconnect() to something else

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`await member.move_to(None)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.move_to). Note that the bot needs the move members permission to do this.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    print(member)
    if str(member) == str("The_person_I_want_to_ban#his_code"):
        await member.move_to(None)
```